# Какое присваивание быстрее по времени?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, типы-данных

Присваивание происходит так в C++(если я ошибаюсь - поправьте меня), задаём тип переменной, называем её и даём ей значение. Если у этого значения другой тип, то он меняется на тот, который задали. По итогу выглядит всё так:

```
<тип_переменной> <название_переменной> = <значение_переменной>
```

Меня интересует момент:

> Если у этого значения другой тип, то он меняется на тот, который задали

Т.е.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 3.03;
    std::cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

Выведет тип `unsigned int` и число  `3`. Но если бы я указал изначально 3, то присваивание произошло бы быстрее, чем изначальное?
Вот ещё примеры:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    long long a = 30L; //long long a = 30
    double b = 3.0; //double b = 3
    short c = 9; //short c = 9.23
    bool d = true; //bool d = 1 (0 - это false)
    return 0;
}
```

Есть ли разница по времени, где я явно указываю, какой тип значения; с примерами после `//`. Или разницы нет?

Comment: Компилятор оптимизирует 100%

Comment: Это не присваивания, а инициализация. Приведения типов будут выполнены еще во время компиляции.

Comment: Harry, а на время компиляции это как-то влияет?

Comment: В этой ситуации вас скорее должно волновать присутствие в коде логической ошибки - отбрасывания дробной части литерала. Либо она действительно не нужна и в самом литерале ошибка, либо она нужна и ее потеря - ошибка. Ну а на время компиляции всякие дополнительные манипуляции конечно влияют в худшую сторону, хотя и на сложно измеримую величину. А если вы начнете компилировать в строгом режиме, включив предупреждения компилятора, то этот код начнет сыпать предупреждениями и даже ошибками https://godbolt.org/z/WxfY31YTe

Comment: @user7860670, Вы хотите сказать, что на время компиляции выражения, где я явно указываю тип значения, я только делаю "хуже" по времени?

Comment: От такой мелочи вы не заметите разницы в скорости компиляции.

Comment: Я хочу сказать, что для начала стоит обратить внимание на корректность, а уже затем на время компиляции, и что любые дополнительные преобразования, особенно сопровождающиеся печатанием предупреждений, на время компиляции влияют негативно.

Comment: Пишите, если хотите быть услышанным, обращение с `@` перед именем... Программирование — наука экспериментальная, замерьте времена компиляции в обоих случаях и посмотрите. Причем компилировать надо многократно, со сброшенными кешами, чтобы нейтрализовать действие иных факторов, и оценить погрешности измерений. И посмотрите на результаты.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сыграем по вашим правилам. Первый код:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 3.03;
    std::cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

Компиляция:

> ```
> $ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion temp.cpp
> temp.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> temp.cpp:7:22: error: conversion from ‘double’ to ‘unsigned int’ changes value from ‘3.0299999999999998e+0’ to ‘3’ [-Werror=float-conversion]
>     7 |     unsigned int a = 3.03;
>       |                      ^~~~
> cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
> ```

Ошибка. Компилятор с максимальным уровнем предупреждений и ошибок такой код отвергает: преобразование из `double` в `unsigned int` не законно. Понизим строгость:

> ```
> $ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion temp.cpp
> temp.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> temp.cpp:7:22: warning: conversion from ‘double’ to ‘unsigned int’ changes value from ‘3.0299999999999998e+0’ to ‘3’ [-Wfloat-conversion]
>     7 |     unsigned int a = 3.03;
>       |                      ^~~~
> ```

Предупреждение есть, но компиляция прошла. Чтобы понять что там, получим ассемблерный код:

> ```
> $ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -S temp.cpp
> temp.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> temp.cpp:7:22: warning: conversion from ‘double’ to ‘unsigned int’ changes value from ‘3.0299999999999998e+0’ to ‘3’ [-Wfloat-conversion]
>     7 |     unsigned int a = 3.03;
>       |                      ^~~~
>
> $ cat temp.s
> ...
> main:
> ...
>   movl    $3, -4(%rbp)
>   movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
>   movl    %eax, %esi
>   movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
>   call    _ZNSolsEj
> ...
> ```

В ассемблере нет константы `3.03` и нет преобразования `double` в `unsigned int`. Время на него не будет тратиться.

Как поменяется время компиляции?

Программа, которая создаёт программу, в которой сто тысяч переменных и сто тысяч преобразований из `double` в `unsigned int`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "int main() {\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
        std::cout << "    unsigned int a" << i << " = 3.03;\n";
    }
    std::cout << "}\n";
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ temp.cpp && ./a.out > temp_.cpp
>
> $ head temp_.cpp
> int main() {
>     unsigned int a0 = 3.03;
>     unsigned int a1 = 3.03;
>     unsigned int a2 = 3.03;
>     unsigned int a3 = 3.03;
>     unsigned int a4 = 3.03;
>     unsigned int a5 = 3.03;
>     unsigned int a6 = 3.03;
>     unsigned int a7 = 3.03;
>     unsigned int a8 = 3.03;
>
> $ tail temp_.cpp
>     unsigned int a99991 = 3.03;
>     unsigned int a99992 = 3.03;
>     unsigned int a99993 = 3.03;
>     unsigned int a99994 = 3.03;
>     unsigned int a99995 = 3.03;
>     unsigned int a99996 = 3.03;
>     unsigned int a99997 = 3.03;
>     unsigned int a99998 = 3.03;
>     unsigned int a99999 = 3.03;
> }
>
> $ time g++ temp_.cpp
>
> real  0m24.953s
> user  0m24.880s
> sys   0m0.064s
> ```

Двадцать пять секунд. Теперь тоже самое но без `double`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "int main() {\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
        std::cout << "    unsigned int a" << i << " = 3;\n";
    }
    std::cout << "}\n";
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ temp.cpp && ./a.out > temp_.cpp
>
> $ head temp_.cpp
> int main() {
>     unsigned int a0 = 3;
>     unsigned int a1 = 3;
>     unsigned int a2 = 3;
>     unsigned int a3 = 3;
>     unsigned int a4 = 3;
>     unsigned int a5 = 3;
>     unsigned int a6 = 3;
>     unsigned int a7 = 3;
>     unsigned int a8 = 3;
>
> $ tail temp_.cpp
>     unsigned int a99991 = 3;
>     unsigned int a99992 = 3;
>     unsigned int a99993 = 3;
>     unsigned int a99994 = 3;
>     unsigned int a99995 = 3;
>     unsigned int a99996 = 3;
>     unsigned int a99997 = 3;
>     unsigned int a99998 = 3;
>     unsigned int a99999 = 3;
> }
>
> $ time g++ temp_.cpp
>
> real  0m24.644s
> user  0m24.564s
> sys   0m0.072s
> ```

Снова двадцать пять секунд.

Вывод: "неправильный" тип не влияет на время выполнения программы, потому что не попадает в программу. "Неправильный" тип не влияет на время компиляции программы, потому что у компилятора много другой работы, на фоне которой разбор констант теряется.

Comment: *"преобразование из double в unsigned int не законно"* - оно законно, компилятор ругается на потерю данных, если изменить double на `3.0`, то все будет ок. *Неправильный" тип не влияет на время компиляции программы* - скорее уж предоставленный пример этого не демонстрирует. Можно было бы там хотя бы предупреждения включить и посмотреть, на сколько долше бы проходила сборка, пока это все дело печатается...

Comment: @user7860670, я пытался на языке ТС объяснить ТС что не надо об этом думать. Вы везде правы, просто подход другой. :)